# Preventing data to load again if there is data already in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer with list of menu items like updates, photos etc..
Here I do fragment transaction based on click in the Navigation Drawer.

```
 int id = item.getItemId();

 if (id == R.id.nav_updates) {
    UpdatesFragment fragment = new UpdatesFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Suppose, if I click `nav_updates`, it replace the frame_container with `UpdatesFragment`. There is no issue in this.

1. If i click the same menu item `nav_updates` again when I'm already in the same page, It loads the data again from server and create a view. But, I don't want to load again If we click the item in Navigation Drawer when we already in the page.
2. While doing the (1) point, It also overlaps. Think I've a viewpager and 2 Tab in `UpdatesFragment`. If i click the item for the first time it loads and shows the 2 Tab. When I click again, It overlaps. That means, when I Swipe, it gets struck and I've to do 2 swipe to reach each tab.
3. When the `UpdatesFragment` has already opened with data, I want to show old data unless I refresh. (Not sure where i want to put network code. onCreate/onCreateView/onActivityCreated)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

I Solved the first issue by,

```
UpdatesFragment fragment_t = (UpdatesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("updates");
            if (fragment_t != null && fragment_t.isVisible()) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            else {
                UpdatesFragment fragment = new UpdatesFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment, "updates");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
```